# "Close encounters" between two big powers: how to solve?

Tags: number-theory

Given integer N, I wander is there is a method to find integers a,b,n,m > 1 such that $N = a^n - b^m$

When N is tiny and a,b,n,m are big the result sounds more interesting, like these examples

$2^{15} - 181^2 = 7$

$13^3 - 3^7 = 10$

$12^3 - 41^2 = 47$

$101^3 - 1015^2 = 76$

$6^7 - 529^2 = 95$

There is another relate question to the previous: can any integer N be written like difference of powers > 1 ?

$1 = 3^2 - 2^3$

$2 = 3^3 - 5^2$

$3 = 2^7 - 5^3$

$4 = 5^3 - 11^2$

$5 = 2^5 - 3^3$

$6 = ??$

$7 = 2^{15} - 181^2  = 2^7 - 11^2$

...

Comment: Do you mean $2^{15}$ instead of $2^15$? If so, try this: `$2^{15}$`.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is 2^(15) but I edited several times and couldn´t render correct view.

Comment: Every a, a+1, 1, 1 will result a 1 result.

Comment: Is this not acceptable? 3^2-3^1=6

Comment: Also this one: 3^2  - 1^1=8

Comment: @Moti The problem asks for $m,n > 1$. Otherwise the problem is trivial: to generate any $N$, just write $N = (N+1)^1 - 1^1$.

Comment: Ok sorry I expressed the quest in poor format way by posting "...difference of powers > 1" but I wanted to say both powers to be > 1. I suppose people understand "not trivial solutions" for this case.

Comment: It is unknown whether $a^m-b^n=1$ has any solutions in positive integers $a,b,m,n,$ all greater than $1$, except $3^2-2^3=1.$

Comment: @Daniel I think you could prove that $a=b+1$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It has been proven, that 8 and 9 are the only powers with difference 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Comment: @MichaelStocker Sorry for not being up to date. I see the proof is from the year 2002

Comment: No need to be sorry :)